# Goole検索のURLからI'm feeling luckyを実行する方法について

Tags: api, google-api, google-search

URLのパラメータを利用してGoogleのI'm feeling luckyを直接実行し，リンクから直接HPに飛べるようにしたいと考えています．
btnIというパラメータを利用すれば良いという情報もあったのですが，正常に動くことと動かないことがあり，動作が安定しません．

動く例:
https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=stackoverflow&btnI
動かない例:
https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=mbed&btnI

用途としてはマークダウンで利用することを考えているため，javascriptは利用できません．
良い方法はないでしょうか

Comment: 関連: https://superuser.com/questions/695110/consistent-im-feeling-lucky-macro-for-google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

こちらではどうでしょうか？
他の例では"tsql"も上記例のURLでは検索できませんね
https://www.google.com/webhp?#btnI=I&q=mbed
https://www.google.com/webhp?#btnI=I&q=tsql